# Is PWA applicable for desktop web application?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, mobile-application

I have recently gone through  couple of Progressive Web application(PWA) articles on google.  What I have got it it is  concept for web application
which combines best of two world i.e. latest browser  features(like web workers etc) and native application(speed, home page etc).

I have two basic doubts .

1. Is PWA applicable for mobile sites only or for desktop based application also ? In the couple of examples I have gone through mainly talks that using
   PWA allows the mobile user to user the mobile sites like app without installing and equally good speed.
2. I understand the point with PWA user does not have to install the native app on his/her mobile but i believe even in case of PWA all content(static content like html,css,jss,images etc) will be stored in cache as user navigates to web application. Service worker checks if content
   available in cache it will serve it from there otherwise fetch it from server. 
   So when PWA caching the content on client side, it will be equivalent
   of size of native app. Is n't it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its applicable to both. Think a PWA as a website that gets stored in local cache.

It really depends on what you configure service workers in the browser to do, but the gist of the thing is:

- cache HTML, CSS, and JS on the client (usually on a per need basis, load and cache)
- use browser local database storage to store data coming from your back end database
- use AJAX, and/or WebSockets to get data back and forth from your back end systems

Call it a website, a javascript application, whatever you call it, its just the same old/new browser tricks working with local cache introduced; so it loads offline.

And loading offline is pretty much as close as they come to a native app, PWAs as of today are HTML, CSS, JS applications running on a browser; generically called a website.

Hope its clear.

Comment: let me just add that this ain't no definition for a PWA, if there is any. Its simply an explanation on how a PWA relates to a native app in the context of understanding of the questioner

Comment: I believe  PWA internally runs in browser though I do not see any browser control on UI?  Also what about the size point 2 in my question ?

Comment: as for the size of the app, that really isn't dependent on beeing a PWA or not. With native app you get compiled binaries of some sort, with a PWA you get the .html .css .js (and all the crap people put on sites). A PWA runs in the browser, its a website! with full qualifications. (not sure what you mean by running internally, its a site can't put simpler than that. About the browser UI stuff, that's just how your browser was coded, and the idea is to give the user a more native app feel, its still a website.